# What limits are there on voting on comments and how do I tell how many votes I have used?

Tags: support, comments, voting

I'm not certain whether something has changed but I don't remember running out of votes for comments in the past. At least, I certainly don't remember running out of them at all often. Then yesterday, I ran out of votes and was told I would have more in 1 hour. Today, I have run out and been told I cannot vote on comments again for 11 hours.

How many votes can I use for comments in what period of time? And how can I check how many votes I have left so as to conserve them for the most important uses when I am running low?

Right now, I'm tending to comment when I would have up-voted a comment but this results in unnecessarily cluttering the comments. I'd like to be able to watch the number of votes I have. In that case, if I'm running out of votes, I could reserve those remaining for cases where I don't otherwise want to comment myself, and refrain from up-voting when I am planning to comment anyway.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide?lq=1 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18994/what-is-the-daily-comment-vote-limit

Comment: Thanks for the links. That's certainly helpful although I don't entirely understand the point of limiting votes on comments, to be honest. I tend to think of them more as communication than anything else. Anyway, I guess I must just have used more than I realised yesterday and today. (That strikes me as odd but there it is.)

Comment: 30 comment upvotes are a lot actually -- I upvote a lot of comments, but I never ran out of comment votes so far.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Theoretically, I agree. At least, I don't remember running out before. (Possibly once at most.) That's why it seemed odd that I ran out two days in a row. I'm just not sure why they are limited since they don't affect reputation and seem to serve purposes solely of communication.

Comment: @cfr: Yes, that's really strange. As far as I know, nobody else reported this issue yesterday or today.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I must just have spent them fast and furiously. I can upvote here, but not on the main site for a bit.

Comment: @cfr: As far as I know, main site and meta has their own voting limit -- 30 votes here and 30 votes there ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Could you write up an answer?

Comment: @Werner Isn't it a duplicate but of a question on another site? How does that work? Not that I object to Christian Hupfer answering. (It will benefit grasshoppers, no doubt.)

Comment: @cfr: You can't make a question a duplicate of another on a *different* site. So either the question is answered here, or it's closed (but not as a duplicate). If it's migrated over to [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com), that's something different, since it'll be closed as a duplicate of the linked post (most likely). I think it's okay to have a question here that can be answered by taking content from the "main meta"; it's happened before.

Comment: @Werner Good ;).

Comment: @Werner: Done! ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was asked by Werner to write an answer, although I am not sure if the question is not already answered by the links Torbjørn T. provided and in the short comment by me.

Each site on StackExchange has a daily voting limit for

- Posts in the sense of questions and answers -- the limit is 40 votes per day, divided into 30 QA - votes (on questions and answers) and additional 10 Q - votes.

  Although this question is not about badges, the explanation for the `Vox Populi` - badge shows some background information here: [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)
- Comments -- the limit is 30 votes per day, explained more detailed here:
  [How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work)

Currently, there is no way to see how many comment votes have been consumed for a current day, there was a question on Meta.SX about a year ago,

[image]

which can be found here: [How to find the number of comment votes remaining today?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186767/how-to-find-the-number-of-comment-votes-remaining-today)

Since a meta site is basically a site of its own, with own badges (but no separate reputation count), the same vote count limits hold for the meta site as well.

The difference in vote counts can be seen, for example, on my today's vote bank account, the snapshots are taken at the same time:

## TeX.SX

[image]

## Meta.TeX.SX

[image]

Comment: Ok, regarding the Meta.TeX.SX snapshot in my post: I should upvote more on Meta ;-)

Comment: while voting on meta.tex.sx is applauded, you've already, proportionally, voted much more there than on the base site, since with over 70,000 questions on tex.sx, and only 1600 on meta, the tex question count is more than 50 times as large as the meta count.  do the arithmetic.